# Getting first item in an array with a specific parameter empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Considering this array :

```
const body = [
  {id: 1,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[]}, {title:"course1.2", results:[]}]},
  {id: 2,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[]}, {title:"course1.2",results:[]}]},   
];
```

I'm trying to get the first item in body that have a course with no results.

I tried this :

`body.filter(session=>session.courses.filter(course=>course.results.length<=0));`

But for a reason that I don't understand it return all items.

Any helps would be really appreciated, thank you!

P.S. I already made some try with Array.some and with a simple forEach, with no luck.

Edit: I forgot to include my jsfiddle test, https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanlaf/4os0fzv1/

Edit2: I know that filter will return all results that match, and that's fine, I can just take the first index of the newly returned array.

Edit3: I actually expect the newly returned array to look like this :

```
const body2 = [
  {id: 2,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[]}, {title:"course1.2",results:[]}]},   
];
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Just added it thank you.

Comment: try using $.grep(body,function(obj,index1){ if ($.grep(obj.courses,function(course,index2){  if ( course.results.length<=0) {return course;   } }).length>0) return obj;     })   Please make sure of syntax errors in my code if possible but grep can useful for you.

Comment: you can control the return result by index number.

Comment: Why would the return look like this when you have empty results in id:1? I am confused. You result only has `id: 2`?

Comment: @Akrion because I'm searching a way to get only items that have no results at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
const body = [ {id: 1,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[{title:"result1.1.1"}, {title:"result1.1.2"}]}, {title:"course1.2", results:[]}]}, {id: 2,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[]}, {title:"course1.2",results:[]}]}, {id: 3,courses: []}];

console.log(body.reduce((r,c) => (c.courses.length ? r.push({ id: c.id, courses: [...c.courses.filter(({results}) => !results.length)]}) : true) && r, []))
```

It uses [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get what you need.

**Update**: Added handling in the case where `courses` is just an empty array with no results e.g. `{id: 3,courses: []}`.

Comment: It's almost working, it's removing the first level of information, so I now receive just the courses with no parent id.

Comment: Oh you mean you need the id?

Comment: I added expected value in the question so you can see what I'm expecting :) Thank you for your help !

Comment: I just ran into an error, if the parent has no course with result, it still return the parent with an empty result, is there a way to get rid of it ?

`const body = [{id: 1, courses: [{title: "course1.1", results: []}, {title: "course1.2", results: []}]}, {id: 2, courses: [{title: "course1.1", results: []}, {title: "course1.2", results: []}]}];`

Comment: Sure give me a few mins

Comment: `body.reduce((r,c) => (c.courses.length ? r.push({ id: c.id, courses: [...c.courses.filter(({results}) => !results.length)]}) : true) && r, [])` should handle that case

Comment: No it's not, since it's verify before the filter occur.

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact input please.

Comment: It was not quite the result I was searching for, I finally get it by adding `.filter(session=>session.courses.length>0)` at the end of the chain. 
`body.reduce((r,c) => (c.courses.length ? r.push({ id: c.id, courses: [...c.courses.filter(({results}) => !results.length)]}) : true) && r, []).filter(session=>session.courses.length>0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could map new objects without mutating the original data.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, courses: [{ title: "course1.1", results: [{ title: "result1.1.1" }, { title: "result1.1.2" }] }, { title: "course1.2", results: [] }] }, { id: 2, courses: [{ title: "course1.1", results: [] }, { title: "course1.2", results: [] }] }],
    result = array.map(o => 
        Object.assign(
            {},
            o,
            { courses: o.courses.filter(({ results: { length } }) => !length) }
        )
    ); 
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nina :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
    const body = [
    {id: 1,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[{title:"result1.1.1"}, {title:"result1.1.2"}]}, {title:"course1.2", results:[]}]},
    {id: 2,courses: [{title:"course1.1", results:[]}, {title:"course1.2",results:[]}]},   
    ];    
    let results = body.find(session => -1 < session.courses.findIndex(course => course.results.length <=0))
    console.log(results)
```

[Array.find() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
[Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)